# HTML Object SVG image does not display

Tags: html, image, url, svg

I had an HTML Object tag like this:

```
<object class="someclass" id="someid" type="image/svg+xml" data="/relative/path/to/svg/file.svg">Your browser does not support SVG files, and so your visualization cannot dislpay</object>
```

This displayed my SVG image file fine. However, I wanted to move the SVG image file outside of the website root, so that users that do not have an account cannot see the file. So the data attribute would become a link to an intermediate page, which would construct the path to the SVG image and show it to the browser.

Now I have:

```
 <object class="someclass" id="someid" type="image/svg+xml" data="/some/intermediate/page?image=/parameter/file.svg">Your browser does not support SVG files, and so your visualization cannot dislpay</object>
```

However, this does not display the image. When I use an Img tag instead, it does display when I right click it and select 'view image'. I tried things such as urlencode the query part of the URL, urlencoding the entire string, replacing the question mark for %3F, switching between Object and Img tags, but it does not seem to work.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe the file is being served with the wrong mime type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem ended up being HTTP header information. SVG images have to be served as `header('Content-type: image/svg+xml')`, and not just as XML

Comment: In my case, I was wrapping a Blob object into a File object and I thought that the File instance would take the type of the Blob but it didn't, so the Object URL I created didn't have the MIME type and the img src failed to load correctly when an SVG was shown

Answer (score 0):

Though the OP has solved his problem, I came across a similar error in which the `object` tag was unable to render the data. The error turned out to be due to the `X-Frame-Options`, which in some cases is by default set to `DENY`.

If this is the case, you need to set to the appropriate value to be able to render.